# How to make a Drupal Portfolio?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have to make a Portfolio for a school project.

I chose Drupal because i wanted to try and learn it.

I have chosen the following theme:
https://www.drupal.org/project/portfolio_zymphonies_theme

I was searching for hours how to add styled content.
I want to add circles with logos in it and the text underneath.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use blocks or [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) if you want to display node content. Probably best to use blocks for your use case.

Another method, would be to edit or create a [template](http://www.kleinermann.com.au/blog/how-to-create-and-use-a-drupal-template-tpl-file/) file. They are located in `/sites/all/themes/YourTheme/templates` folder.

To style stuff, you need to use [CSS](https://www.google.ca/search?q=CSS&oq=CSS&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i65l2.1200j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), so edit your theme's `.css` file.